# Powershell try catch catches exception but -ErrorVariable doesn't

Tags: powershell

The following code catches exception (because of invalid path) and goes to the catch block:

```
try
{
    Test-Path "HKLM:\test [C:\test]"
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "exception caught"
}
```

However this one does not store anything in the errorVariable:

```
Test-Path "HKLM:\test [C:\test]" -ErrorVariable errorVariable
```

Can someone explain what is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception occurs in binging phase, before cmdlet actually executed. So `Test-Path` cmdlet not executed and not write any errors in its error stream.